# Error encrypting connection strings in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: iis, encryption, sitecore, sitecore6

I've been able to successfully encrypt a connectionstings.config file, but when do this and replace the file with the encrypted version , I get the error: [InvalidOperationException: Unknown connection string. 'core'].

I did this by opening a command line as adminstrator on the server, and executing
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "x:\xxx\app_config\" which produces a web.config file in that directory, the contents of which I cut and paste into the connectionstrings.config.  I've tried including the  node and not including it.  Is there something else that I need to do to make this work properly?

Comment: Are you connecting from the same machine you used, to do the actual encryption?

Comment: Yes, I'm remoted into the machine when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially what I was doing was running aspnet_regiis on a directory (app_config) that had no web.config in it, only a connectionstrings.config.  When I executed, it wouldn't come back with an error, but would create a new web.config that had an connectionstrings node with encryption information.  It seems that aspnet_regiis isn't smart enough to tell you it's found no source file to encrypt, but instead "tricks" you into believing it's created a new encrypted connectionstrings node by creating a new web.config with what is essentially nothing in the encryption.  You wouldn't know this without either trying to use this connection string, or I suppose decrypting it to find no contents.

So, what I had to do was to take the connectionstrings.config file and copy it, then rename that copy to web.config, making sure there was a configuration node surrounding the connectionstrings node, THEN running aspnet_regiis, then copying the changed web.config's connectionstrings node and replacing the one in the connectionstrings.config file.  I'm not even sure how common it is for Sitecore instances to use a seperate connectionstrings.config file in the app_config directory, but in case yours does, hopefully this will save some time and effort in encrypting these connectionstrings!